# Given a binary search tree, print all combination of inputs that forms the same BST

Tags: data-structures

For example,

input binary tree is

```
     2 
3         1
```

we need to print all possible combinations that for the same binary tree structure (tree balancing not needed)

231, 213

Note : 123 is not a valid output since , it will change the tree structure .

It gets complicated if the pattern is lengthier.

another example

```
         5 
      3     7
   2    4  6   8
```

in this case

5 3 7 2 4 6 8

5 3 2 4 7 6 8

5 7 3 2 4 6 8

...............

I would like to know if there is any algorithm to find patterns which gives the same binary tree.

Comment: You mean binary **search** tree, correct? (A regular binary tree doesn't imply any ordering of nodes) You'll need to elaborate on exactly how you're allowed to generate this tree from the given pattern. For example, is `1 2 3 4 5` a valid pattern for the tree in your example? If not, why not?

Comment: I have updated the question now... let me know if it is not clear

Comment: You mentioned that `123` is not valid because it will change the tree structure, but, since you didn't give rules as to how the tree is generated from the pattern, there's nothing preventing the tree you drew from being a valid tree for `123`. I presume you assume the pattern is the level-order traversal of the tree (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Types), but you absolutely need to explicitly state this.

Comment: I have answered this question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211701/given-a-bst-and-its-root-print-all-sequences-of-nodes-which-give-rise-to-the-sa

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple algorithm using backtracking in Python. It assumes an implementation of a binary search tree with an `insert` operation. Each node has a value at `node.value`, and possibly children at `node.left` and `node.right`.

```
def get_children(node):
    children = []
    if node.left is not None:
        children.append(node.left)
    if node.right is not None:
        children.append(node.right)
    return children

def print_permutations(possibilities, string):
    if len(possibilities) == 0:
        print(string)
        return

    for i in range(len(possibilities)):
        node = possibilities[i]
        del possibilities[i]
        new_possibilities = get_children(node) + possibilities
        print_permutations(new_possibilities, string + " " + str(node.value))
        possibilities.insert(i, node)
```

The idea is that every time you select a node from your list of possible candidates for the next number, you add that node's children to your list of possible candidates. Once there are no more candidates, you have arrived at one possible ordering.

You might call it like this:

```
b = BinarySearchTree()
b.insert(5)
b.insert(3)
b.insert(7)
b.insert(2)
b.insert(4)
b.insert(6)
b.insert(8)

print_permutations(get_children(b.root), str(b.root.value))
```

And it will output:

```
5 3 2 4 7 6 8
5 3 2 4 7 8 6
5 3 2 7 6 8 4
5 3 2 7 6 4 8
5 3 2 7 8 6 4
...
```

Comment: Your answer works, but you use a list that takes linear time for insertion and deletion. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68543202/839733) for a faster implementation.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is harder than it looks on the surface.

Consider the tree from your first example:

```
  2
1   3
```

As you say, there are two possible orderings of input: `2,1,3`, and `2,3,1`. The rule is: root, then children in any order.

But that's too easy. To see the full complexity of the problem, you have to extend it to another level. Thus, your second example:

```
      5 
   3     7
2    4  6   8
```

There are in general two ways to construct this tree: breadth first, or depth first. To do it breadth first, you repeatedly apply the "root first, then children in any order" rule. Thus:

```
5,3,7,2,4,6,8
5,3,7,2,4,8,6
5,3,7,2,6,4,8
...
5,7,3,8,6,4,2
```

At each level there are (2^k)! permutations, where k is the level. So there is 1 permutation at the root, two permutations at the second level (k == 1), 24 permutations at the next level, etc.

But doing this breadth first will not generate all of the possible valid inputs. For example, `5,3,2,4,7,6,8` is perfectly valid. To get all of the valid inputs, you have to include depth-first construction, as well. And here things get kind of interesting.

You can generate a pre-order traversal of the tree: `5,3,2,4,7,6,8`, or a reverse pre-order traversal: `5,7,6,8,3,2,4`. The rule here is root, then traverse the children depth-first in any order.

But that doesn't cover the odd case of `5,3,2,7,8,4,6`, which just kind of skips around but makes sure that a node's parent is supplied before any of its children.

I don't have a complete solution, but I can give you the beginning of an algorithm. Consider the case of randomly generating a valid input sequence. You can do that with a loop:

```
nodes_array = create an array of nodes that can be selected
output_array = array of selected nodes

add root to nodes_array
while nodes_array is not empty
    temp = randomly select node from nodes_array, and remove it
    if temp.left != null
        add temp.left to nodes_array
    if temp.right != null
        add temp.right to nodes_array
    append temp to output_array
end while
```

That should always generate a valid input because a child node is never added to the output array unless its parent has already been selected.

The problem of generating all valid combinations, then, becomes a problem of changing that random selection step so that at each level it generates all possible permutations of the `nodes_array`. Generating permutations is a solved problem. Applying that recursively, though, will take a bit of thought.

Answer (score 0):

I went for a very simple approach: using recursion print the nodes in the following order: root>left child>right child

Please note: The other valid sequence: root> right child> left child can likewise be printed.
For simplicity I am giving here code for the 1st type of valid sequence.

Here is my code:

```
class Node: 
  
    # Constructor to create a new node 
    def __init__(self, data): 
        self.data = data 
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

root = Node(20) 
root.left = Node(8) 
root.right = Node(22) 
root.left.left = Node(4) 
root.left.right = Node(12) 
root.left.right.left = Node(10) 
root.left.right.right = Node(14)
```

The meat of the problem:

```
def printNodes(root):
    
    if root == None:
        return False
    else:
        print(root.data)
        printNodes(root.left)
        printNodes(root.right)
```

Output:

```
printNodes(root)

20
8
4
12
10
14
22
```

Answer (score 0):

@deleterOfWorlds' answer works, but he uses a list that takes linear time for insertion and deletion. Here's my Python solution with plenty of explanation.

We build each array from left to right by choosing for every position one node out of a set of possible choices for that position. We add the node value to the path, and the children of the node (if any) to the list of possibilities, then recurse further. When there are no further choices we have one candidate array. To generate the rest of the the arrays, we backtrack until we can make a different choice and recurse again.

The catch is to use a suitable data structure for holding the possibilities. A list works, but the node has to be put back in the previous position while backtracking (order matters, since we have added the children of the node which must be visited AFTER the node). Insertion and deletion from a list takes linear time. A set doesn't work since it doesn't maintain order. A dict works best since Python dictionary remembers the insertion order and all operations run in constant time.

```
def bst_seq(root: TreeNode) -> list[list[int]]:
    def _loop(choices: MutableMapping[TreeNode, bool], path: list[int], result: list[list[int]]) -> None:
        if not choices:
            result.append([*path])
        else:
            # Take a snapshot of the keys to avoid concurrent modification exception
            for choice in list(choices.keys()):
                del choices[choice]
                children = list(filter(None, [choice.left, choice.right]))
                for child in children:
                    choices[child] = False
                path.append(choice.val)
                _loop(choices, path, result)
                path.pop()
                choices[choice] = False
                for child in children:
                    del choices[child]

    result = []
    _loop({root: False}, [], result)
    return result
```