# Count number of unique node sequences producing the same BST

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

The problem:

> Given a particular sequence of up to 50 integers, which represent
>   nodes of a certain binary search tree (BST), how many permutations of
>   this sequence are there, which will also give rise to exactly the same
>   BST? Include the original sequence in your total count as 1 sequence.
>
> For instance, answer = 6 for such a sequence [5,2,1,9,8]: [5,2,1,9,8]
>   (itself, the original sequence given), [5,9,8,2,1], [5,2,9,1,8],
>   [5,9,2,1,8], [5,2,9,8,1], [5,9,2,8,1]

Comment: `give rise to exactly the same BST? ` can you explain more about this? does this mean the sequence printed when you traverse the tree?

Comment: to maintain the tree insertion order in his example sequence, 2 must be inserted before 1, 9 before 8, and 5 before all of them. However the insertion order of 2 or 9 can be swapped since they are on opposite sides of the tree. Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211701/given-a-bst-and-its-root-print-all-sequences-of-nodes-which-give-rise-to-the-sa

Comment: @BenGrimm: yes, it's basically that duplicate qn; but I don't need to enumerate, I need to count and figure out how many there are.

Comment: @PhamTrung: `give rise to exactly the same BST?` - well, as in my example, if I were to take the given sequence and build a BST from it, I want to count the total number of unique node sequences I can obtain by flattening that BST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have your example sequence `[5,2,1,9,8]`.  The first node will become the root of the binary tree, so we know the first node must be 5.

From then on, all the nodes smaller than 5 will go to the left child, and all the nodes greater than 5 will go to the right child.

So you can solve this **recursively**, count the number of ways of making the left subtree (consisting of `[2,1]`) *multiply by* the number of ways of making the right subtree (consisting of `[9,8]`) and *multiply by* the number of ways of ordering the arrival of integers on opposite sides.

### Sample code

```py
def nCr(n,r):
   """Return number of ways of choosing r objects from n"""

   top, bottom = 1, 1
   for i in xrange(r):
      top *= n
      n = n - 1
      bottom *= r
      r = r- 1
   return top / bottom

def count_ways_to_make_bst(seq):
    if len(seq)<=1:
        return 1
    num_remaining = len(seq) - 1
    left = [r for r in seq[1:] if r>seq[0]]
    right = [r for r in seq[1:] if r<seq[0]]
    return count_ways_to_make_bst(left) * count_ways_to_make_bst(right) * nCr(num_remaining,len(left))
```

Answer (score 2):

Assume that the given node sequence is the order in which we added those elements into the BST.

We can easily see that if two nodes a and b belong to two different branches, so the order of adding a and b will **not affect** the final structure.

We only need to ensure that the **parent need to be added first**, before its children is added.

For the example [5,2,1,9,8]: 5 should always added first.

There will be only two choices: add 2 or add 9

- If we add 2: 1 can be added in any order
- similarly, If we add 9: 8 can be added anytime after that

So, now we have our algo while travelling from root -> leaf:

```cpp
int numberOfWays (Node node) {
    if(node is leaf) return 1;
    int a = numberOfWays(node.left);
    int b = numberOfWays(node.right);
    int x = number of node in the left;
    int y = number of node in the right;
    //nCr is combination, so we can choose x places in total of x + y positions
    return nCr(x+y,x) * a * b;
}
```

Comment: Why is nCr(x+y, x) multiplied ?